# People have many things to say about me

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

- You could say I'm straight, or you could say I'm gay.
- You could say I'm a virgin, or you could say I've had sex.
- You could say I've always been the youngest of my family, or you could say I had a little brother.
- You could say I'm just as happy to date a man as a women, but you can't say I'm Bi.
- You could say I'm queer, but not that I'm LGBT.

But the real question is can you explain how all those statements about me are true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is to do with

> Words which have multiple meanings

You could say I'm straight, or you could say I'm gay.

> "Straight" can mean *frank or candid*, "gay" can mean *happy*, in which case one does not contradict the other.

You could say I'm a virgin, or you could say I've had sex.

> "Virgin" can mean a person who is inexperienced in a usually specified sphere of activity (e.g, a skydiving virgin) so the statements here are not necessarily contradictory.

You could say I've always been the youngest of my family, or you could say I had a little brother.

> "Little brother" may just refer to a brother who is physically smaller (not necessarily younger).

You could say I'm just as happy to date a man as a women, but you can't say I'm Bi.

> Perhaps "just as happy to date a man as a woman" means you don't want to date either men or women (not necessarily suggesting asexuality but maybe you just don't like dates).
>  **Original Answer:** "Date" can mean to determine the period of time to which something belongs, so perhaps you are an archaeologist who has to work out from whence fossilised remains date.

You could say I'm queer, but not that I'm LGBT.

> "Queer" can just mean strange or odd, so the statements here are not necessarily contradictory.

Comment: almost right, except for the dating one.  That one isn't just a play on multiple meanings, care to take another try at it?

Comment: rot13(creuncf Pneoba vf abg Ovfzhgu?)

Comment: @dsollen I've edited to try something else. If it's not right, I may give MacGyver88's helpful suggestion a shot.

Comment: The more I read the question, the more random my "helpful" suggestion becomes. LOL

Comment: There you go.  to be exact I'm straight, but aromantic.  I'm not dating anyone.  I don't want to get cooties!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A worm?

Explanation:

> Worms aren't gender differentiable; they have the same organs. When two worms made, either one of them may end up carrying the baby.

Comment: A very interesting idea.  but since all of these statements actually apply to the real me I sure hope it's not the answer :P